# Trouble reading int from file in Python

Tags: python, file

How to I convert the line to ints if there are multiple ints in a line. (In finish the line might be "2 4" and finish = int(line) causes and error.

Also, how can I access specific elements of transitions in the for loop at the bottom. I know I can print the list but I need to compare specific elements?

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\College\Theory of Computation\dfa19btest.txt', 'r') as f:
   for i, line in enumerate(f):
   if i == 0:
       language = line
       print("Language =", language)
   if i == 1:
       numstates = int(line)
       print ("Number of states =", numstates)
   if i == 2:
       start = int(line)
       print ("Start =", start)
   #if i == 3:
       #finish = int(line)
       #print ("Finish =", finish)
   if i >= 4:
       transitions.append(line)
       print ("Transitions = ", transitions[i -4])

for x in range(numstates-1, -1, -1):
    print(transitions[x])
    # string is in 4 a 2 b 3 format
    # if [0] == [3] then answer insert [2]* into answer array
    # if [2] and [4] are followed by same number insert [2]|[4]
```

Comment: Should be just `numstates = int(numstates)`, but it is dangerous to use `i` in both for loops: you don't necessarily need enumerate (use `f.next()`)

Answer (score 0):

To parse an string to an integer use : [int](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#int)

for exemple :

```
str_var = '123'
int_var = int(str_var) # int_var now have the interger value 123
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what should occur if any of your input is invalid, i.e. non-integer.  The following is a simplified example for Python2.  Note the try/except clause.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\College\Theory of Computation\dfa19btest.txt', 'r') as f:
   for i, line in enumerate(f):
       if i == 0:
           language = line
           print("Language =", language)
       try:
           if i == 1:
               numstates = int(line)
               transitions = np.array(numstates)
               print ("Number of states =", numstates)
           if i == 2:
               start = int(line)
               print ("Start =", start)
           if i == 3:
               finish = int(line)
               print ("Finish =", finish)
       except ValueError:
           print "Invalid int (%s) on line: %d" % (line, i)  # use print() for Python3
           break
```

Comment: Thanks, although is there something else needed if there are multiple ints on a line. On line finish the line reads "2 4" and runs into an error.

Comment: That is a change from your original question which implied there was only one integer per line to read.  What do you want to do if there are multiple integers?

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry I forgot finish could have multiple states. This is supposed to convert NFA to regular expression. I think having it as a string will work and I can compare its elements with elements of transitions.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple ints on a line, the str.split() function will be useful: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
a = "1 2 3 4"
print a.split()   -> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

The end of your question is unclear-- what are you trying to do with the specific elements?